# Count rows with entries based off specific ID in first column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to figure out a formula that will give me the count of entries made for each ID. So for ID 112233 the count would be 2 and for ID 445566 the count would be 3.

[image: Example]

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>")`?

Comment: So why don't you expect 3 for 112233 and 4 for 445566 ? However, try unique() to generate the ID list, then countifs() as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, perhaps for readability & simplicity one could use `GROUPBY()` provided using `MS365` with `Beta` Version enabled.

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(A2:A8,B2:B8,COUNT,,0,,B2:B8<>"")
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(x, UNIQUE(A2:A8), y, COUNTIFS(A2:A8,x,B2:B8,"<>"),HSTACK(x,y))
```

---

**Note:** Ensure to use `Structured References` aka `Tables` instead of using the whole range which may slow down the working functionality of excel!

---

Or, Use `Pivot Table` like as shown below.

[image]

---

- `ID` needs to be placed in rows area,
- `Value` needs to be places in values area and ensure to summarize as `COUNT`.

---

Edit: For the `GROUPBY()` approach it doesnt needs the last param as well the following is suffice.

```
=GROUPBY(A2:A8,B2:B8,COUNT,,0)
```

---